# How to test WebService/Restful API in Rest Client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, web-services, api, rest

I know this question may be so simple but still posting here.
I have a WebService/Restful API written in RAILS which gives response in JSON format. According to the RAILS developer, it works fine under his development but not in my case.

**My problem is,**

> Now, I want to test that Request/Response in Browser Rest Client (like
>   mozilla, chrome). However, when I hit the API there it gives me 401.

**So I have 2 questions,**

```
1] How to test it in Rest Client? if I make any mistake while passing header parameter in wrong way.

2] Is there anything other approach to do this?
```

API Details are,

**URL** : http://rails4.xxxxx.com/xx/xxxxx/{id}.json

*//{id} can be any integer value*

**header**

X-xxxxxx-Client: 
487txxxxhu34hfixxxxxu3hfcfxxxxx4f3f3f

For more details, please refer below snaps.
Thanks is advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: VVB,please dont get me wrong, you can able to test it in POSTMAN  right, then why do you want to test it over browser as well?

Comment: Did you mean do you an to write automate test case, to test the RESTful API?

Comment: Hi @RameshKumarThiyagarajan I  have  very small idea about. I just want to know how can I test this means the JSON which I should get in the response

Comment: I have installed it, please let me know about the next step

Comment: Please refer the documentation for more information about [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/)

Comment: @RameshKumarThiyagarajan Tested on POSTMAN, but didn't work, please check the attached snap.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101502/discussion-between-ramesh-kumar-thiyagarajan-and-vvb).

Comment: If you have a developer creating a rails application for you he should specify the api parameters exactly including authentication. Any answers here would be pure speculation as we know nothing about the API you are calling.

Comment: Noting the point, but just want to be clear from my side before consulting with Rails Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to wrong credentials.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to test rest api:

cURL (CLI) 
RestConsole (for Chrome) 
 
RestAssured (java test framework) 
Frisby (javascript test framework)